# How to manipulate class properties from exception handlers in Java?

Tags: java, oop, exception, try-catch

Is there a way to manipulate instantiated class properties from the exception handler?
Lets say there is a class Automobile with name and price,
And there is a custom exception,
Within the driver class, I instantiate the class and try to create the car

```
String name = "car name";
Double price = 222.00;
try {
Automobile car = new Automobile(name, price) //creates the car object
}catch(CustomException e) {
     e.fix()
}
```

And within the fix method, the Custom exception instantiate a valid car object. How to set the car object from above to the car object generated from the exception. The condition is that the Custom Exception cannot return anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can split declaration and assignement and declare `car` outside of the `try`-block as follows:

```
String name = "car name";
Double price = 222.00;
Automobile car = null;
try {
    car = new Automobile(name, price); //creates the car object
} catch (CustomException e) {
    car = e.fix();
}
```

Comment: But the exception can not return anything, that is the case